# Bootstrap 3 tooltip gets wrapped on every white space?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

After Upgrading to bootstrap 3 the tooltips are getting wrapped on every white space.

I believe that this is happening because of the grid.

So if I select a column col-sm-3 for a textbox and If I place the tooltip on right it wraps all the white spaces and shows it as below.

[image]

If I do the data-placement=top then everything seems okay.

[image]

I played around with css to get it work.

`.tooltip-inner {
   white-space:nowrap;
   }`

[image]

but this is also not acceptable that it should wrap when it is longer than lets say 200px.

How can I fix this? I would like to place the tooltip on the right

here is the form

```
 <div class="form-horizontal"> 
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BasicDescription, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BasicDescription, new { @class = "tip form-control", data_toggle = "tooltip", title = "Please enter a short description here, exceeding no more than 100 characters", data_placement = "right" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BasicDescription)
    </div>
  </div>
</div
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify a min-width like this..

```
 .tooltip {min-width:200px;}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/kFfEAk0m1O

Comment: I have accepted the answer but now I have another issue. if the tooltip is only one word it shows it 200 px length and it doesnt look good at all?

Comment: You can further specify the CSS selector for the wider tooltip (ie; tooltip-wide), and then only apply this class where you have wide tooltips.. http://www.bootply.com/TR2m68ySO2

Answer (score 5):

instead of setting min width, consider removing the max-width limitation:

```
.tooltip-wide .tooltip.bottom, .tooltip-inner  {
  max-width: none;
}

<a [tooltip]='acctTooltip' class='tooltip-wide' placement='bottom'>blah blah</a>
```

(tooltip-wide is to keep the css from affecting other tooltips)

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the same problem by simply switching the title attribute's string directly from `" " to "&nbsp;"`

```
<html>
    <!-- From: -->
    <a ... data-placement="right" title="Click to zoom"></a>
    <!-- To: -->
    <a ... data-placement="right" title="Click&nbsp;to&nbsp;zoom"></a>
</html>
```

You can also leave a regular `" "` that will break line for multi-line tooltips.

Comment: Superb solution, much better than forcing tooltip widths.

Answer (score 1):

As hardcoded tooltip `width` or `min-width` lead to other issues for me and adding non breakable spaces is not readable/suitable especially for dynamic or long texts, I was looking for another solution.

It seems to have some dependency on the parent width as adding the attribute `data-container="body"` solved this issue for me.