# ngx-bootstrap with bootstrap3 set tooltip width

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, ngx-bootstrap

I need to increase the width of the ngx-bootstrap tooltip, I've tried every solution I could find without success.

HTML:

```
<a [tooltip]='acctTooltip' placement='bottom'>{{item.AccountNumber}}
...
<ng-template #acctTooltip>
    <!--TODO: figure out how to get the tooltip width to widen-->
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Title &amp; Address:</th>
                <td>
                    {{item.Title1}}<br /> {{item.Title2}}
                    <br /> {{item.Title3}}
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>C/M:</th>
                <td>{{item.CreditType}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>ServiceType:</th>
                <td>{{item.ServiceType}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Role:</th>
                <td>{{item.Role[0].Capacity}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

[UPDATE]
placing this in style.css does cause it to rotate 45 degrees (for verification), the background can be shrunk but not expanded. 
so there's something more in the inner html.

```
.tooltip.bottom  {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-right: none;
    max-width: none;
    height: 10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: Add your CSS that you currently have for the ToolTip.

Comment: this is all I have, if I could figure out the css I wouldn't be asking :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what worked for me using ngx-bootstrap V3.3.0.

**HTML**

```
<div class=" tooltip-350" [tooltip]="LONG_TOOLTIP_TEXT" placement="top">
   Hover Over me!
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
::ng-deep .tooltip-350 ~ .tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  max-width: 350px;
  min-width: 350px;
}
```

A custom class, ".tooltip-350", is added to be able to uniquely select the container the tooltip is applied to.

ngx-bootstrap creates a sibling element with class ".tooltip" that can be selected using the "~" general sibling selector.

The actual width of the tooltip is controlled by a class called ".tooltip-inner" which is selected using the descendant selector (just a space between classes/elements/etc.).

The "::ng-deep" is required since this is selecting an element inside a child component rather than an element directly in the component. Alternatively, these styles could be added to the global style sheet without the need for "::ng-deep".

Putting all this together gives the above CSS selector.

The properties that control the width in this case are "min-width" and "max-width" so by setting that to whatever values desired, the width of the tooltip can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to your element and put `min-width` to your class in css.

**html**

`<a class="tooltip-acct" [tooltip]='acctTooltip' placement='bottom'>{{item.AccountNumber}}`

**css**

`.tooltip-acct {
    min-width: 150px;
}`

If you want to get the actual width of the `tooltip`, you can use `[style.width]="foo"` in your element. Them all you have to do is to create a foo var in your component and get/set the width. Note: Do not forget the `;` in the value (i.e `150px;`)

Comment: this didn't change the width of the  tooltip, though it did seem to change a width value INSIDE of the tooltip.

Comment: but you want to change the `width` of the tooltip or the `size` of it?

Comment: i want to change the width or somehow force a nowrap.  I'm displaying an address inside the tooltip; as is it wraps the text.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24245131/3681565) worked with this nowrap words

Comment: upvoting your answer, it wasn't quite what I was after but it got me on the right track.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately went with this after some excellent help from Gaspar. it turned out the max-width property was getting me and needed to set both .bottom and inner.

```
.tooltip-wide .tooltip.bottom, .tooltip-inner  {
  max-width: none;
}

<a [tooltip]='acctTooltip' class='tooltip-wide' placement='bottom'>blah blah</a>
```